# Compute elevation and azimuth from lat, lon, and altitude

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, elevation, matlab, angles

Given the latitude, longitude and altitude of two points (in my case satellite and ground antenna) I would like to compute the azimuth and elevation angle between the two points from the ground station.

My idea would be the following (doing it in matlab):

```
% convert the lat, lon, and altitude data into ENU

[E,N,U] = geodetic2enu(lat,lon,h,lat0,lon0,h0,wgs84);

% and then compute elevation and azimuth the following:
Az = atan2(E,N);
El = atan(U / sqrt(E^2 + N^2));
```

Could that be right?